# GWT server side database connection - cannot find oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDrive

Tags: java, gwt, oracle10g, database-connection, gwt-rpc

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle 10g database on the server side of a gwt application. Currently I'm getting this exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. (full stack trace below)

I have added [ojdbc14.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) to my build path, and the same code works when I run it inside a main() method in its own (non-gwt) project.

Here is a simplified version of my code that still crashes in the same way:

```
public class DataUsageServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements UsageDataService {

    @Override
    public ServerDataTable getUsageData() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ServerDataTable thisTable = new ServerDataTable();
        return thisTable;
    }
}
```

I think you can safely ignore the ServerDataTable class that I wrote. The exception occurs before.

I thought I might need to tell gwt about this module in some way, so I tried adding the following tag to the MyProject.gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'/>
```

but this crashes saying "[ERROR] Unable to find 'oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.gwt.xml' on your classpath"

And just for kicks I tried copying ojdbc14.jar to my WEB-INF/lib directory and adding that copy to my build path, but still no luck.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Stack Trace of Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at ca.gc.nrcan.geod.intranet.server.DataUsageServiceImpl.getUsageData(DataUsageServiceImpl.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)*
```

Comment: What server are you deploying on? Can you make sure your actual deployed war has the ojdbc14.jar in WEB-INF/lib and also that its a valid jar

Comment: @kal I'm using Jetty for both development (with GWT Eclipse plugin) and on my deployed webapp server. The deployed WEB-INF/lib does NOT contain ojdbc14.jar though I did try copying it there (in the development environment). I'm not sure how to test if it is a valid jar, but it did function correctly when I made a simple java console application.

Comment: --Make sure it is in WEB-INF/lib .. You can do this when you are building your app. You can also try to brute-force it by including it in the server's classpath and restarting the server.

Comment: @kal ok, I put the file back in WEB-INF/lib and it does seem to have changed something (even in development mode). I'm getting a different error at least. I'll have to wait until after the weekend to dig into it though. Thanks so far. I'll post an update on Monday.

Comment: Sure thing. Do post an update.

Comment: @kal This did seem to fix the initial problem, though it has introduced another. My server complains `java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package oracle.jdbc.driver` which is usually caused by loading a jar more than once. I've made sure that ojdbc14.jar is not on my build path (though it is in WEB-INF/lib). I can't think of where else it could be trying to load this jar.

Comment: Actually, here's some of the stack trace:
`java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal package oracle.jdbc.driver: already loaded at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:235) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188) at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:404) at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Web`

Comment: Ok. Looks like you have two different jdbc drivers in your classpath. Check if you have any other ojdbc*.jar file in either your Jetty classpath or your WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @kal Thanks for you help Kal. Your comments have been very helpful and I seem to have gotten past this error. I still can't connect to my database, but I'm at least loading the drivers. I'd happily accept your answer if you write one.

Comment: Thanks @grayob. I'll post one ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have two different jdbc drivers in your classpath. Check if you have any other ojdbc*.jar file in either your Jetty classpath or your WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

Comment: I think I was holding my breath as I tried this, but unfortunately I get the same exception.
'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'